# What is PathData.Types for GraphicsPath and how to use them values?

Tags: c#, types, points, graphicspath

I am wanting to write a string to a GraphicsPath object in c# like below

```
'
   path = new GraphicsPath();
   path.AddString("Hello World", FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 1, 80, new Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericDefault);

'
```

But I then want to take the generated path and write it to a 3d file in this case Sketchup.

Do not worry about sketchup, I just need to work out the meaning of the path.PathTypes which are a byte[] but there is no meaning for it in the documentation at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathdata.types?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Drawing2D_PathData_Types

The documentation states the following rather useless descripion

**An array of bytes that specify the types of the corresponding points in the path.**

But there is no description of the byte or bit meanings.

Does anyone know the real breakdown of each byte?

[image]

When I render the data points without any interpretation of the meaning of the bytes in the PathTypes variable I get the following.

[image]

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathpointtype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks - I should have found i myself. Cheers

Comment: They are flags regarding the point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathtypes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 I believe this documentation was added after you posted the question, as it's marked relevant to .Net 5.0, but I'm seeing the same values in 4.8.